# Why does SciPy return `nan` for a t-test with samples with 0 variance?

Tags: python, scipy, nan, hypothesis-test

I am using [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) in Python and the following return a `nan` value for whatever reason:

```
>>>stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)

>>>stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan).
```

But whenever I use samples that have different summary statistics, I actually get a reasonable value:

```
stats.ttest_ind([1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2])
Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.66666666666666663, pvalue=0.54146973927558495).
```

Is it reasonable to interpret a p-value of `nan` as `0` instead? Is there a reason from statistics that it doesn't make sense to run a 2-sample t-test on samples with the same summary statistics?

Comment: I think that the problem is that ttests include a division by the standard deviation. I would instead check if the standard deviation is 0 because there may be other cases where it returns nan (not sure what they would be though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Division by zero will raise the NaN (= not a number) exception, or return a floating-point representation that, by convention, matches NaN.  Be particularly careful of divide-by-N versus divide-by-N-minus-one standard deviation formulae.

Comment: Shouldn't that comment be "Be [...] careful of divide-by-N versus divide-by-N-**minus**-one [...]"?